# jQuery Select Value From Dropdown Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to get the value from dropdown but I am getting the value of only 1st dropdown. There are multiple records which are coming from the database along with each record there is a drop-down menu in which status of the product is mentioned.

I am getting the value of only 1st-row dropdown. Here is my code:

jQuery code

```
$(".myBtn").click(function(){  
    var id=$(this).attr("atr");  
    var text = $(".hotel[myid='tayyab']").val();

    alert(text);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'updatestatus.php',
        data: {id:id,status:text},
        success: function(data){
            $("#results").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

This is my PHP code

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db=mysql_select_db("eshop");
    $id=$_POST['pid'];
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userorder WHERE id LIKE '$id%'");

    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $id=$res["id"];
    ?>

    <table class="table table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $res["id"];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $res["name"];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $res["productname"];?></td>
                <td>
                    <select class="hotel" myid="tayyab" name="ostatus">
                        <option value="cancel">Cancel</option>
                        <option value="underp">underp</option>
                        <option value="deliver">deliver</option>
                    </select>
                    <button atr="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="myBtn">Change Status</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: val() returns the selected option of a select input, so it always just returns one result. in case no option has the selected attribute it will have the value of it's first option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am getting the value of only 1st-row dropdown.

Because that's what

```
var text = $(".hotel[myid='tayyab']").val();
```

says to do. You're doing a *global* search for `.hotel[myid='tayyab']` and then using `val` to get the value of the first match.

Instead, you want to find the `tr` containing the specific button that was pressed, and then search for `.hotel[myid='tayyab']` *within* that `tr`:

```
var text = $(this).closest("tr").find(".hotel[myid='tayyab']").val();
```

---

Side note: Custom attributes should always start with a [`data-` prefix](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes), e.g. `data-myid`, not`myid`.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a unique `myid` to every dropdown based on the id, like so:

```
<select class="hotel" myid="tayyab_<?php echo $id; ?>" name="ostatus">
  <option value="cancel">Cancel</option>
  <option value="underp">underp</option>
  <option value="deliver">deliver</option>
</select>
```

Then in jQuery:

```
$(".myBtn").click(function(){

    var id=$(this).attr("atr");  

    var myId = "tayyab_"+id;
    var text = $(".hotel[myid='" + myId + "']").val();

    alert(text);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'updatestatus.php',
        data: {id:id,status:text},
        success: function(data){
            $("#results").html(data);
        }
    }); 
});
```